# MySQL Foreign Keys in strong entity

Tags: mysql, sql, key

Both Entities are strong, Perfil(Profile) and Utilizador (in english User) are indentifiable by the nif and UserID in that order. As you can see I have a Foreign key do Profile table in User table, in this second one is it needed to declare NIFId and put it on it's primary key as I have in the commentary (`--primary key(UserID, NifID)`) or should I declare NIFId as an unique atribute, or the third option don't declare it there since it isn't nedded.
Thank you very much!

```
create table Perfil(  
  nif char(9),              
  profile_type int(1) NOT NULL,         
  nome varchar(45) NOT NULL,  
  telefone char(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,  
  DataBirth date NOT NULL,  
  CHECK(profile_type==0 OR profile_type==1)  
  primary key(nif)  
);  


create table Utilizador(  
  UserID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  -- NifID char(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,  -- Is it needed to declare this atribute  
  role int(3) NOT NULL ,                 -- varies from 1 to 3  
  username varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,  
  password varchar(15) NOT NULL,  
  -- primary key(UserID, NifID),   
  primary key(UserID),  
  FOREIGN KEY (NifID) REFERENCES Perfil(nif)  
);
```

Comment: You know MySQL only parses `CHECK` clauses but not uses them right (unless the latest MySQL 8.0.13 update supports them which i doubt)? If you want to `CHECK` it not need to simulate it with INSERT and UPDATE triggers

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks Sir, yes I forgot about that aspect of MySql. Thanks for that, but still in doubt if it is needed to declare the atribute NifID and put it with the primary key.